# pandas replace multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is sample dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],  'b':[11, 22, 33, 44, 55]})
>>> df
      a   b
   0  1  11
   1  1  22
   2  1  33
   3  2  44
   4  3  55
```

Now I wanted to update/replace b values that are matched on a column from other dict based on index

ex:

```
match = {1:[111, 222], 2:[444, 555]}
```

output:

```
      a   b
   0  1  111
   1  1  222
   2  1  33  <-- ignores this bcz not enough values to replace in match dict for 1 
   3  2  444
   4  3  555
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way. The idea is to calculate a cumulative count by group and use this to filter rows. Use `itertools.chain` to create a single array of values. Finally, use `pd.DataFrame.loc` and Boolean indexing to set values.

```
from itertools import chain

count = df.groupby('a').cumcount() + 1

m1 = df['a'].isin(match)
m2 = count.le(df['a'].map(match).map(len))
values = list(chain.from_iterable(match.values()))

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'b'] = values

print(df)

   a    b
0  1  111
1  1  222
2  1   33
3  2  444
4  2  555
```

Comment: Just be careful with ordering. My answer assumes your input dataframe is ordered by `'a'` and that your dictionary is "insertion ordered" by key [assuming you are using Python 3.6+ where dictionaries are insertion ordered].

Comment: Awesome works fine, is it good to do like this on huge dataset, match dict

Comment: @sunny, In my opinion, this should be pretty efficient for large datasets. Just make sure your ordering is aligned as per my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the pop function of list:

```
import pandas as pd


def pop(default, lst):
    try:
        return lst.pop()
    except IndexError:
        return default


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55]})

match = {1: [111, 222], 2: [444, 555]}

df['b'] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda e: pop(e[1], match[e[0]]), axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   a    b
0  1  222
1  1  111
2  1   33
3  2  555
4  2  444
```

if the order must be preserved, you can always pop the first item:

```
def pop(default, lst):
    try:
        return lst.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
        return default
```

**Output**

```
   a    b
0  1  111
1  1  222
2  1   33
3  2  444
4  2  555
```

**UPDATE**

A faster (non-destructive) way is to use [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
def pop(default, lst):
    try:
        return lst.popleft()
    except IndexError:
        return default

match_deque = {k: deque(v[:]) for k, v in match.items()}

df['b'] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda e: pop(e[1], match_deque[e[0]]), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Note: `apply` + `lambda` is just a thinly veiled loop, not recommend when vectorised solutions are available.